# Action Builder enable global intent language confusion when setting multiple languages

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

I enabled the multi-language and global intent options in my Action Builder. When I checked the "Deep link to my_intent" column, I found that the language was confused, mixed with various languages, and did not switch with the language.
[deep link in en](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFIbE.png)
[deep link in ko](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wj1r.png)

---

Because the language of the word is wrong, the global intent does not take effect in my scene test ,
how to fix it?